# How to include querystring in Redirects

Tags: sxa, redirect

I need to redirect to certain page based on querystring value.

For Ex:

**Case 1**

Old Url: /cs/satellite?code=10015

New Url: /Redirects/page1

**Case 2**

Old Url: /cs/satellite?code=10016

New Url: /Redirects/page2

**Here is how I want**

[image]

**But, when I save the respective redirect item, the entry is getting modified like below:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not allowed due to usage of the Name Value List field type in that `Mappings` field which only allows keys containing letters and numbers due to the Validate() method in it. See further details here:

- [Why Sitecore does not allow to use special characters in Name Value List field as a key?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/726/why-sitecore-does-not-allow-to-use-special-characters-in-name-value-list-field-a)

In your case also second option on how to find match and that is to use `Regular expressions` won't work because you would still need to use special characters:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/map-a-url-redirect.html

In the thread in first link, there is mentioned possible workaround. Please take a look and try to implement. I don't know whether this will be still compatible with SXA at the end.

You could also solve redirection outside of Sitecore and SXA on IIS level for example with `URL Rewrite` module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite